# How do i install redis extention to windows apache server

Tags: windows, redis, xampp, wamp

Step 1: Install redis and start server service https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads 
Step 2: Download php_redis.dll extesion and etc. files from https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/2.2.7/windows
Step 3: Set in php.ini that extension=php_redis.dll 
Step 4: Restart apache server and check phpinfo()

And i got no extension what am i missing?

Comment: Windows 10 x64, usıng wamp and xampp both php 5.6

Comment: maybe useful? : https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/releases. You can install it as a service if you wish. You need a PHP client such a `predis` etc. see: http://redis.io/clients.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already did it, maybe it's about OS

Answer (score 3):

From Step 2:
https://pecl.php.net/package/redis/2.2.7/windows

Make sure you have download the **correct package**. 
Package must be downloaded as per **your PHP Version** and **thread safety of PHP**.

http://www.web-technology-experts-notes.in/2016/12/how-to-install-redis-on-wamp-server.html

Answer (score 0):

thank you
Make sure you have download the correct package. Package must be downloaded as per your PHP Version and thread safety of PHP.

http://www.web-technology-experts-notes.in/2016/12/how-to-install-redis-on-wamp-server.html